# How to turn off a scanner that is connected through a serial port programmatically, using c#?

Tags: c#, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I am using `Datalogic Magellan 9400i` to scan barcodes. When a barcode is scanned I want to programmatically turn off the scanner for a short period of time.

I went through a lot of manuals but can't find a solution anywhere.

Code for scanning items:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 7, StopBits.One);
    port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
    port.ReadTimeout = 1000;
    port.WriteTimeout = 1000;
    port.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    port.Open();        
}

private void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    bytesRead = port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    koda = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    MessageBox.Show(koda);
    port.Close();          
}
```

Comment: You're telling the thread to sleep for 1 second. In that one second the barcode scanner can still send it's signals, so it will send one second worth of data before closing the serial port. At least that'd be my explanation.

Comment: Some clarification: 1. Do you really need to turn the scanner off? I would say it is enough to ignore incoming data for "x time" (= Set/reset a bool with a timer, for example and test it in DataReceived). 2. Why is this code in your Form? It should be in a separate class.

Comment: 1. I am trying to disable the scanning for a while(stop beeping, turn the lights off) 2. Im just testing the scanner so far.

Comment: _"I'm just testing the scanner so far."_ If this is not intended for production, then ignore that part of my comment.

Comment: For example, in this document [Product Reference Guide](https://www.elzab.com.pl/download/io/io_Magellan9400i_9300i.pdf), there are scanner command lists on page 481 for PDF and page 469 for printing. Each command has 1 byte, 'E'(0x45) is Enable, and 'D'(0x44) is Disable. Please try it.

Comment: Yes this is what I was missing thank you

Answer (score 0):

Where do you tell the scanner to "turn off"? Closing the Serial port will only end the Serial communication, but you Need to send a command to the scanner to do something.
For example: (I don't know the manual)

```
port.WriteLine("turn off");
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that 1. OP does not _need_ to actually turn off the scanner and 2. there is no "turn off" signal to send to the scanner. That's not how they work, usually.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you cannot (and actually you do not need to) "turn off" the scanner (as in physically power off), so let me suggest a "dead time":

```
private DateTime _lastSeen = null;
private void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime localNow = DateTime.Now;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        bytesRead = port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
         // TODO magic number "1 second" to be replaced by Config-Value or Const
        if( _lastSeen == null || (localNow  - _lastSeen) < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) 
        {
            koda = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            MessageBox.Show(koda); // <-- I'd reconsider this, too.
        }
        // port.Close(); // Do not close the port here.         
        _lastSeen = localNow;
    }
```

Disclaimer: This is untested and intended to show an idea. You'll perhaps also have to make sure it is threadsafe.

Also consider: If the data is not guaranteed to be read in one `Read`, you'll have to introduce one additional layer of abstraction here.